# how to weight gradient in different examples

Tags: tensorflow

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
n_data = 5
x_data = np.matrix(np.random.randn(n_data, 3))
coef = np.matrix(np.arange(1, n_data + 1)).T
print x_data
# print np.sum(x_data, axis=0)
# print np.multiply(coef, x_data)
print np.sum(np.multiply(coef, x_data), axis=0)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))
w = tf.Variable([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]], dtype=tf.float32)
coef = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], shape=(n_data, 1), dtype=tf.float32)
res = tf.matmul(x, w)
res_new = tf.multiply(coef, res)

grads = tf.gradients(res_new, w)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    re = sess.run(grads, feed_dict={x: x_data})
    print(re)
```

Assume I have a dataset `x_data`, each row is an example with dim = 3, then I have a 3 * 2 weight matrix `w`, my output is x_data * w. Then I want to get the gradient of the weight matrix. So I use `tf.gradients` . But it seems to sum the gradients for each example directly. What I want is to sum the gradients of each example by a distribution. So I use a `tf.constant` `coef` as the distribution. It works well. However my problem is I don't know what to do if coef is also a tensorflow variable. When it also depends on w, I can't use `tf.multiply(coef, res)` simply.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to use `tf.multiply(coef, res)` when `coef` is a variable?

Comment: @Neal if `coef` is also a variable, then the derivation would be different. That's d(coef*res)/dw != coef * dres/dw

Answer (score -1):

When you create your `coef` variable you can pass it the `trainable=False` parameter. With this your optimizer will not modify it during training. Citing the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable):

> `trainable`: If `True`, the default, also adds the variable to the graph
>   collection `GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`. This collection is used as
>   the default list of variables to use by the `Optimizer` classes.

Comment: No. I only want tf.gradients to treat coef as a constant, but optimizer still trains it.

Comment: In the code snippet you provided, you define `coef` as a `tf.constant`. By definition it will _not_ be trained. if you define `coef` as  `coef = tf.Variable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], trainable=False, dtype=tf.float32)` it will not be trained. Are you saying you tried both of these methods and `coef` got trained nonetheless?

Comment: I mean I cannot set trainable=False for coef. Although I don't want it to be trainable in tf.gradients, in other places I need it to be trainable. But once I set trainable=False for coef, I can't set it to True

Comment: @T.NG Could you find a way to compute weighted gradients?

Comment: @user3480922 No. I switched to PyTorch